# Oracle - Unique constraint while allowing null values

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm a bit new to PL-SQL coming from T-SQL.

I have a requirement that only one phone number is allowed per user ID, but the phone number column *can* be null as many times as required.

So table is:

| User ID | Phone Number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL |
| 1 | 9735152122 |
| 1 | NULL |
| 2 | NULL |
| 3 | NULL |
| 1 | 2124821212 |

It's that last one I need to block, although the first three are fine.  In this case I'm talking about the sample table I've posted, not the actual table order.  I just need to allow the NULLs through but block if there are duplicate phone numbers per a given User ID.

I've read about functional indexes but not sure exactly how to apply them here.

Comment: You say "first" and "last"; since rows in a table have no inherent order how do you define the order of these rows in your table? Can you include that column in your sample since it's relevant to the question?

Comment: @JNevill That is just relevant to the table posted.  I'm not talking about the order in the actual table.  I'll edit to clarify.  The table can have a million rows and these can be the 5,00th and the 1 millionth.  Just an example.

Comment: Then how would you know that you want to delete `2124821212` instead of `9735152122`? What logic would you use to determine which one should be blocked?

Comment: @JNevill I'm looking for a unique constraint I can apply to the table so that the 1 millionth row is not allowed in due to earlier data violating the constraint.  And nothing is being deleted.  The INSERT should be disallowed.  I'm simply dealing with a legacy schema design and trying to tighten up data integrity here.

Comment: Got it! This isn't existing table data. You are wanting to pop a constraint violation when that new record hits. That makes more sense. Sorry for not picking up on that sooner. I was all prepared to whip up some psql, but constraint definitions in Oracle is not a subject matter I'm an expert in. I think this clarification will help folks stumbling into this question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_index ON my_table (
  CASE WHEN phone_number IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE user_id END,
  phone_number
)
```

With this logic, if `phone_number` is NULL, then both values in the index will be `NULL`, so that row will be excluded from the index.  If `phone_number` is not NULL, then the row will be included in the index with the actual values for `user_id` and `phone_number`, and uniqueness will be enforced.

P.S. This is not "PL/SQL", it is Oracle SQL. PL/SQL is the procedural language used to write such things as triggers, functions, etc.